# base64 json_decode issue - php

Tags: php, mysql, json

Fetching BLOB from mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT data as datajson FROM tablename";

$res=$obj->_executeQuery($sql);
$res=$obj->getAll($res);

$blobdata = $res[0]['datajson'];
```

My json data from BLOB looks like this

```
[{"name":"propose","value":"Propose~sample"},
{"name":"expenseamount","value":"Expense Amount~15246"},
{"name":"paymenttype","value":"Payment Type~    Cash"},
{"name":"img0","value":"/9j/4AAQSkZHIjks........61A/3qBo/9k="},
{"name":"img1","value":"NO"}]
```

Now

```
{"name":"img0","value":"/9j/4AAQSkZHIjks........61A/3qBo/9k="}
```

This pair is a base 64 string which is included in my BLOB. And when i did `json_decode($blobdata);` i am getting `null`

The exact base64 string can be found in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rod5raem/)

I have added `json_last_error();` in my code

```
switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }
```

Which returns  **- Syntax error, malformed JSON** and 
json_decode does not work, since this is not a proper json

I want the details other than img0 and img1

1 . Now how do i remove the last two pairs (img0, img1) BEFORE json_decode, so that this becomes valid json.

2 . Or how to convert the base64 string to become proper json

**UPDATE**

This is how BLOB data is storing in mysql

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value) 
{
    $raw_data[] = array('name' => $key, 'value' => $value);
}
$json = json_encode($raw_data);
$sql="INSERT INTO tablename (data) VALUES ('$json')";
```

Comment: Please, share a part of code, that converts to base64 your images and saves it to blob

Comment: Ideally it would be useful if we could see the full JSON string that is causing problems to work out why it's causing problems.

Comment: @yergo i have given the update.

Comment: @Jon, Basically i have a problem with img0 and img1 which contains base64 strings

Comment: Why are you trying to `json_decode` a base64-encoded string? `json_decode` is used to decode a JSON-encoded string, not base64-encoded.

Comment: @Passerby my blob data contains both base64 string as well as normal string. how do i neglect base64 string when `json_decode` of blob data?

Comment: My requirement to get the data other than img0 and img1

Comment: @Matarishvan That in itself shouldn't cause a problem. The JSON as you've provided seems to decode fine for me which makes me think there's something in the string that you've omitted is causing the problem in decode. Basically what I'm asking for is a replication case that we can test.

Comment: @Jon Stirling. I have provided the the full base64 string in JSFIDDLE. couldn't put it in the code, since its too long.

Comment: @Matarishvan That also seems to decode fine? See https://3v4l.org/P5ebD

Comment: @Matarishvan I'am starting to suspect, that as `BLOB` type itself does not store charset, your code may work properly if you store your json in `TEXT` field... Recalling that json for php has to be in utf8.